# Is there a pyOpenSSL wrapper for SSL_get_current_cipher?

Tags: openssl, pyopenssl

that is a way to get the actual cipher suite in use for a connection?
get_cipher_list seems to return the "possible" cipher suite, that the client (or server) support.

Comment: Now when this case is resolved for TCP, probably somebody can help me with the same problem in DTLS. I've just posted a new question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583508/how-to-get-current-cipher-in-pyopenssl-for-dtls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from OpenSSL._util import (
ffi as _ffi,
lib as _lib)
```

...

```
c_cipher_obj = _lib.SSL_get_current_cipher(con._ssl)
cur_cipher = _ffi.string( _lib.SSL_CIPHER_get_name(c_cipher_obj))
```

where 'con' is your OpenSSL.SSL.Connection object that has been already used to connect to a server or to do a handshake.

I don't know why pyOpenSSL developers didn't add this method. M2Crypto does have it.

Answer (score 1):

master@HEAD has introduced `OpenSSL.SSL.Connection.get_cipher_name`. and `OpenSSL.SSL.Connection.get_cipher_bits`.  These will be available in pyOpenSSL 0.15.