# How to get current cipher in pyOpenSSL for DTLS

Tags: python, openssl, handshake, pyopenssl, dtls

I need to get a negotiated cipher for DTLS protocol in pyOpenSSL. I was successful in doing that for TCP sockets, but when it comes to datagrams, it's not that obvious. Please provide an example either in C or Python. This is what I've tried so far:

```
import socket
from OpenSSL import SSL
from OpenSSL._util import (
    ffi as _ffi,
    lib as _lib)


DTLSv1_METHOD = 7
SSL.Context._methods[DTLSv1_METHOD]=getattr(_lib, "DTLSv1_client_method")
ctx = SSL.Context(DTLSv1_METHOD)
ctx.set_cipher_list('AES128-SHA')
ctx.use_certificate_file("path-to-cert.pem")
ctx.use_privatekey_file("path-to-key.pem")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(('dtls-host', 443))
con = SSL.Connection(ctx, s)
con.set_connect_state()
con.connect(('dtls-host', 443))
cc = _lib.SSL_get_current_cipher(con._ssl)
print _ffi.string( _lib.SSL_CIPHER_get_name(cc))
```

The printed result is
    (None)

Answer (score 1):

The result is None because that is the cipher that has been negotiated for your connection.  Or rather, it is None because *no* cipher has been negotiated for your connection yet.  Cipher selection is part of the handshake and the handshake is not done anywhere in this example.

Try `con.do_handshake()` before calling `SSL_get_current_cipher`.

Also bear in mind that `_`-prefixed names are private and you really shouldn't use them if you want your program to keep working with future versions of pyOpenSSL.

Comment: Tried handshake, but it hangs forever. In regard of '_', there is no other way to get to DTLS stuff except through native C calls, because pyOpenSSL didn't implement DTLS method and SSL_get_current-cipher function. Also in TCP case connect does include handshake. I've seen examples in plain C for DTLS where connect is called without calling do_handshake. Unfortunately, I didn't see any working examples in Python. Thanks for answering.

Comment: If you can't complete a handshake then you have another problem.  Perhaps the way you've hacked together DTLS support doesn't actually work.

Comment: Not likely. If you unpack pyOpenSSL.egg and check SSL.py, you'll find that it's just a very thin wrapper around native C lib, except that not all C functions and SSL methods have been wrapped. What I'm doing, is the same as in SSL.py - wrapping missing C functions and SSL methods. I think, a reasonable approach for me would be to test it with pure C first to completely rule out the possibility of bad hacking.